# Putty clearing sessions

Tags: putty, hotkeys

My team is responsible for a small task using `putty.exe` but they handle many tasks a day.

Basically we connect to host `i-sentinel` providing a username and password.

Therefore, it is entered a username of the person that requires their session cleared and exit.

What i am in need is a way to launch `putty.exe` from keyboard command then login to host perhaps using a script to save time.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. What is your operating system? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @stephen, help me understand, what OS are you on? Can you give any details on what command you're running on the remote server?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered trying KiTTY? 
It supports automatic login when connecting to a host!

Short description of KiTTY: 
KiTTY is a fork from version 0.63 of PuTTY, the best telnet / SSH client in the world. 
KiTTY is only designed for the Microsoft Windows platform.

[Read more here](http://kitty.9bis.net/)

Binding kitty to start with a keystroke shouldn't be too hard!

Edited:

Make a bat file running the command to load a specific session in kitty.

```
kitty.exe -load sessionname
```

Ofcourse the exe got to be placed at the same location on all computers running this, but that could be as easy as "C:\kitty".

The bat file can then be assigned a keyboard shortcut - completing what you were after.

Comment: you recommended the software for automatic login, but still did not address the real question that is to assign a keyboard key combinaton to launch the client.

Comment: OK so I can create a .bat file which launches Kitty or keyboard shortcut. But what is the correct code to complete the connection and login username and password boxes?

Comment: This is the automatic logon script page for Kitty (http://kitty.9bis.net/) unfortuantely filling in a .txt file via logon script. I can't work out how to have this txt file always in Kitty.

Comment: I think my question is now how do I launch a saved session in putty from either a script or commandline rather than launching Kitty interface.

Comment: @stephen To launch from cmd, use the -load flag. (kitty.exe -load NAME) where NAME is the session name from your list. Tested and worked like a charm on a few hosts for me.

Comment: @stephen updated my answer aswell.